# What does <T> before the return type of a method mean?

Tags: java, generics, generic-method

The following method returns a List composed of `T` type elements:

```
public <T> List<T> getList() {
    return new ArrayList<T>();
}
```

In the signature we have `<T> List<T>`. The `List<T>` makes sense, because that is the type of the **return value**.  What is the need for the preceding `<T>` though?

The code doesn't compile without both `<T>` and `List<T>`. Leaving out the `<T>` gives

> Cannot resolve symbol T

---

I have read the official Oracle tutorial on [generic methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html). It explains that this is part of the syntax:

> The syntax for a generic method includes a list of type parameters, inside angle brackets, which appears before the method's return type.

But it does not really explain why it is needed in the first place or what exact effect it has on the method.

Comment: `<T>` is a generic type parameter. It's indicating that this is a generic method. Otherwise there's no indication what `T` is supposed to be.

Comment: The first <T> indicates this is a generic method. The second <T> is part of List<T> which is the return type, indicating that the method returns a list of the generic type parameter. Note that the first <T> is NOT part of the return type. You could also have a <T> void sendTheList( List<T> theList ) method

Comment: @GonenI you are right.  I couldn't compile sendTheList without the <T>.  But any idea why the compiler can't simply infer the type from the return or parameter generic type without the extra <T>? Or any further reading you can point me to?

Comment: Ignore the `<T>` and you could have `public List<Object> getTheList() { return new ArrayList(); }` - the generic type is what you define with `<T>`, and without that you would have to make it a "raw" type. Generics add type checking for sanity purposes, the runtime was kept (mostly) ignorant (there is an extra cast added by the compiler) of the existence of generic types.

Comment: [Generic Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html)

Comment: @jaco0646 I had read that link earlier.  It only explains that the parameter list is required.  It doesn't explain why.

Comment: @JamesTaylor You can rollback the edit if you think it is misleading. In my opinion it is more on-topic, easier to find via google and thus increasing the help you will receive from others. I did not intend to do you any bad. I am not sure why you think that this is not answered by the tutorials. Take a look at the link jaco posted, it says _"The syntax for a generic method includes a **list of type parameters**, **inside angle brackets**, which appears **before the method's return type**."_. And then it has an example `public static <K, V> boolean compare(...)` which shows exactly that.

Comment: Just to help you increasing your experience at SO. If you include your research results, and why they did not answer your question, inside your question, that will increase the quality of your question. People will then not downvote for lack of research etc. So, for example, you could have posted that link and then explain why it did not answer your question _"It explains that we need it, but not why"_. Otherwise we can not know that you did your research and why it didnt help you.

Comment: @Zabuza regarding "you could have posted that link and then explain why it did not answer your question" - thanks for explaining.  You are right and I will keep that in mind in future.  I have deleted my comment about the edit since the latest edit adds clarity to the post.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first `<T>` signifies that the second `T` is a placeholder for a generic parameter and not the actual name of class which you are going to store in that list.

Without that first `<T>` compiler will treat `T` as a class name (like `Object`, `String`, etc) try to find a class named `T` in the same package where the class with that method exists or in the import section of the class with that method. And if compiler is unable to find class named `T` it will show compilation error.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense.  Also explains why without the `<T>` I get an error saying "Cannot resolve symbol T"

Comment: Thank you  for this answer! Perfecto.